# Exporting variable in angular AoT compiler

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-aot

I tried to implement dynamic configuration as can be seen in this [post](https://christianlydemann.com/implementing-dynamic-environments-in-angular-for-avoiding-one-build-per-environment/).

Everything works in JiT compiler, but I get

```
ERROR in Error during template compile of 'environment'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'Environment' was called.
```

when trying to build with the AoT compiler.

This is my `environment.ts` (note class Environment is exported):

```
export class Environment extends DynamicEnvironment {
  public production: boolean;

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.production = false;
  }
}

export const environment = new Environment();
```

I would still like to use the environment in the standard way `some.component.ts`:

```
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

console.log(environment.config.property);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by creating `config.module.ts` and `config.service.ts`. Config module declares providers:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    ConfigService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: (appConfigService: ConfigService) => () => appConfigService.loadAppConfig(),
      deps: [ConfigService],
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class ConfigModule {}
```

Usage of config service in `some.component.ts`:

```
@Component(...)
export class SomeComponent {
  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) { }

  private myMethod() {
    console.log(this.configService.get.property);
  }
}
```

For tests, json testing config file is imported:

```
import { default as appTestConfig } from '../../../../assets/app-config.test.json';
```

and set directly on config service:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  ...,
  imports: [
    ConfigModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: (appConfigService: ConfigService) => () => appConfigService.setConfig(appTestConfig),
      deps: [ConfigService],
      multi: true,
    },
  ]
}).compileComponents();
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't. Seriously, stay away from those two files (`environment.ts` and `environment.prod.ts`). Those are NOT about the DevOps meaning of the word "environment", they are about debug constants.

If you need to know if you're running a debug build, import [isDevMode](https://angular.io/api/core/isDevMode):

```
import { isDevMode } from '@angular/core';
```

If you need dynamic configuration, just read a Json from somewhere or have the server side inject it as a script tag, then read it directly or via Dependency Injection (it's not that hard to do).

But don't mess with those files. Trust me, you'll thank me later ;)